# proof of $\pi_1(S^n)=0$ if $n\geq2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the hatcher's proof of $\pi_1(S^n)=0$ if $n\geq2$.
but it is challenging for me to understand each step.

> We can express $S^n$
> as the union of two open sets $A_1$
> and $A_2$ each homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$
> such that $A_1 ∩ A_2$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n−1} \times\mathbb{R},$ for example by taking $A_1$ and $A_2$ to be the complements of two antipodal points in $S^n$
> .

how do we know the "union of two open sets $A_1$
and $A_2$ each homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$" and $A_1 ∩ A_2$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n−1} \times\mathbb{R}?$

Can anyone explain more about this part?

Comment: What exactly is unclear in this quote?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Actually ,the whole quote

Comment: Try visualizing the case $n = 2$. Take $A_1$ to be the complement of the north pole, and $A_2$ the complement of the south pole. Can you make sense of what's going on then?  (As an aside, don't say "the hatcher's", say "Hatcher's".)

Comment: Are you saying for instance that you do not understand what the complement to a point means? Or, maybe you do not understand why the complement to a point is homeomorphic to $R^n$? If you want to get a meaningful answer, it is in your interest to explain the precise source of your confusion.

Comment: You seem to be parsing that quote incorrectly. Let me add a few words and some extra punctuation: *We can express $S^n$ as the union of two open sets $A_1$ and $A_2$ such that the following hold: $A_1$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$; and $A_2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$; and $A_1 \cap A_2$ is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1} \times \mathbb R$. We can do this, for example, by choosing two antipodal points $P_1$ and $P_1$ in $S^n$, and by taking $A_1 = S^n - \{P_1\}$ and $A_2 = S^n - \{P_2\}$*.

Comment: @LeeMosher How is the intersection of A_1 and A_2 homeomorphic to Sn−1×R? Can you explain it more?

Comment: You can visualize the case $n=2$ by using [latitude--longitude coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#/media/File:FedStats_Lat_long.svg), with $P_1$ as the north pole of $S^2$ and $P_2$ as the south pole.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you I will try,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be concrete, let $S^n$ be the sphere $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i^2=1$, and take $A_1=S^n\backslash\{(0,\ldots,0,1)\}$, $A_2=S^n\backslash\{(0,\ldots,0,-1)\}$ (i.e. remove the north and south poles respectively).

You can give rigorous arguments that the $A_i$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (e.g. stereographic projection) and that
$$
A_1\cap A_2=A_1\backslash\{\text{pt.}\}\cong\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}\cong S^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}
$$
(e.g. for the second homemorphism, consider $x\mapsto x/\|x\|$).

While Hatcher's statement is meant to be intuitively "obvious" (as are many arguments in topology, abusing geometric intuition for the sake of efficiency), you should take the time to give more rigorous arguments a few times until you develop the intuition.